# Copy folders into Azure data storage (azure data factory)

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, copydataset

I am trying to copy folders with their files from ftp into an azure data storage, by looping through the folders and for each folder copy the content into a container that has the folder's name. for this, I used a metadata ,for each and copy data component. For now I am able to copy all the folders into the same container , but what I want is to have multiple containers named after the the folders in the output, each one containing files from the ftp.

ps : I am still new to azure data factory

Any advise or help is very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Get Metadata activity before the for-each. The Get Metadata activity will get the files in the current directory and pass them to the For-Each. You connect it to your Blob storage folder.

try something like this

**Setup a JSON source:**

[image]

Create a pipeline, use **GetMetadata activity** to list all the folders in the container/storage. Select fields as **childItems**

[image]

Feed the Metadata output (list of container contents) into **filter activity** and filter only folders.

[image]

Input the list of folders to a ForEach activity

[image]

Inside **ForEach**, set the **current item()** to a variable, and use it as a parameter for a parameterized source dataset which is a clone of original source !

[image]

[image]

This would result in listing the files from each folder in your container.

Feed this to another filter and this time filter on files. Use `@equals(item().type,'File')`

[image]

Now create another pipeline where we will have our **copy activity** running for each file found to be having same name as that of its parent folder.

Create **parameters** in the new child pipeline to receive the current Folder and File name in the iteration from Parent Pipeline to evaluate for copy.

[image]

Inside child pipeline, start with foreach whose input will be the list of filenames inside the folder received into parameter:  `@pipeline().parameters.filesnamesreceived`

[image]

Use variable to hold the current item and use **IfCondition** to check if filename and folder names match.

[image]

> **Note:** Try to evaluate dropping the file extension as per your requirement as metadata would hold the complete file name along with
> its extension.

If True - > the names match, copy from source to sink.

[image]

Here the **hierarchy is preserved** and you can also use "Prefix"  to mention the file path as it copies with preserving hierarchy. It utilizes the service-side filter for Blob storage, which provides better performance than a wildcard filter.

The sub-path after the last "/" in prefix will be preserved. For example, you have source container/folder/subfolder/file.txt, and configure prefix as folder/sub, then the preserved file path is subfolder/file.txt. Which fits your scenario.

[image]

This copies files like `/source/source/source.json`  to `/sink/source/source.json`

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy is simplest solution for this than Data factory, dry run can be used to check which files/folders will be copied

```
az storage blob copy start \
  --destination-container destContainer \
  --destination-blob myBlob \
  --source-account-name mySourceAccount \
  --source-account-key mySourceAccountKey \
  --source-container myContainer \
  --source-blob myBlob
```

Comment: In the destination , I dont want all folders to be copied in the same container, but to have one folder per container.. this where I get stuck not in copying the files